# Print bash script argument passed into a new script generated by your current script

Tags: bash

Title might be confusing -- I'm writing up a bash script that creates another bash script in the same relative directory, and I want to print an argument passed into the second script.

Layout:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  if [[ ! "$2" =~ ^-[^-].* ]];
    case $key in
      --arg1 | -t)
        arg1=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --arg2 | -k)
        arg2=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --arg3 | -i)
        arg3=$2
        break
        ;;
      *)
        ;;
    esac
  fi
done

cat <<'EOF' > secondScript.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  if [[ ! "$2" =~ ^-[^-].* ]]; then # don't gobble up next key if this key doesn't have a value
    case $key in
      --finalArg1 | -t)
        finalArg1=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --finalArg2 | -k)
        finalArg2=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --finalArg3 | -i)
        finalArg3=$2
        break
        ;;
      *)
        ;;
    esac
  fi
done

echo ${finalArg1}
EOF

chmod +x secondScript.sh

./secondScript.sh --finalArg1 {arg1} --finalArg2 {arg2} --finalArg3 {arg3}
```

so the end result is `arg1` printed to the console. Instead, this code just prints
`{finalArg1}`. Any way to do this?

Comment: Remove the single-quotes from `cat <<'EOF' > secondScript.sh` and variable-expansion will occur. (if I understand what you are asking...)

Answer (score 0):

Ah nvm this was just an oversight -- Forgot to add `$` to substitute the variables on the second script call. Should look like this:

```
./secondScript.sh --finalArg1 ${arg1} --finalArg2 ${arg2} --finalArg3 ${arg3}
```